# How to specify an IComparer for a particular property on a model that can be used for Silverlight DataGrid column sorting

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, icomparer

I have a Silverlight datagrid with a column who's binding is set to a string property on the model. These strings are alphanumeric, so I have created a custom IComparer to sort them appropriately. My question is how can I force the grid to use this custom comparer when sorting by this column?

One of my ideas was perhaps there is some attribute that can be applied on the model's string property that I am binding to, that would explicitly specify the comparer to use when comparing this value with another string?

Answer (score 0):

If you bound your grid to your ViewModel, then you use the ICompare in the get of your property that is bound to your View.

Comment: Bellow you will find a better example of property to bound to your ListItem source.

Comment: You should consider merging your two answers (possibly posing them as alternatives).

Answer (score 0):

Like the property bellow, but in your case you should return using your ICompare.

```
private ObservableCollection<ListOfMyClassType> myGridItemSource;
public ObservableCollection<ListOfMyClassType> MyGridItemSource
{
      get { return myGridItemSource; }
      set { myGridItemSource = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyGridItemSource");}
}
```